# Remove duplicates from a python list so that the last instance remains

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following list:

```
start = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2]
```

I want to remove the duplicates so that the **last** instance remains. So the result would be:

```
result = [1, 4, 5, 3, 2]
```

I've written the following function:

```
def keep_last_instances(start):
    result = []
    
    total_counts = Counter(start)
    current_counts = {}
    for x in start:
        total_count = total_counts[x]
        current_count = current_counts.get(x, 0) + 1

        if current_count == total_count:
            result.append(x)
        else:
            current_counts[x] = current_count
    
    return result
```

Is there a faster/cleaner way?

Comment: using built_in functions `list(dict.fromkeys(reversed(start)))[::-1]` for `python3.7+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1, `O(n) + O(k log k)` time, `O(n)` storage, where `k` is the number of unique keys.

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2]
mapping = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(nums)}
return sorted(mapping.keys(), key=mapping.get)
```

Option 2, `O(n)` time, `O(n)` storage:

```
seen = set()
result = collections.deque()

for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):
    if nums[i] not in seen:
        seen.add(nums[i])
        result.appendleft(nums[i])
return result
```

Comment: In option 2, I think it's more clear to use reversed: `for x in reversed(nums)` - how does that affect the speed?

Comment: @JohnnyMetz You can reverse in `O(n)` time, so theoretically, it doesn't change the Big-O time complexity going from `O(n)` to `O(2n)` . But for time-sensitive apps, constants matter. I'm guessing you use case isn't time sensitive, since you wouldn't be here looking for advice from strangers if you were building an Air Traffic Control system. Choose what looks simpler to you.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve it:

```py
start = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2]
list_ = []
set_ = set()
for c in start[::-1]:
    if c not in set_:
        list_.append(c)
        set_.add(c)
print(list_[::-1])
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 5, 3, 2]
```

We reverse the list in `O(n)`, and **then** iterate through it in `O(n)`. Checking if element already exists takes `O(1)` due to the `set` data structure. In total it takes `O(n)` time complexity.

Comment: There's no need to reverse the list twice if you start from the end. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69114632/839733.

Comment: You are right, ```collections.deque``` has an ```appendleft``` method that works in ```O(1)```. For list, I can use ```insert``` to prepend elements, however it makes the algorithm work in ```O(n^2)```. Switching to ```collections.deque``` is a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
import collections

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
index_to_remove = collections.deque([])
for i, elem in enumerate(A):
    # If same element exists in rest of the list, get it's index
    if elem in A[i+1:]:
        index_to_remove.appendleft(i)
        
for index in index_to_remove:
    A.pop(index)
print (A)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 5, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Inserting at the beginning of a list will shift all elements to the right, making this an `O(n^2)` algorithm. That's why a `deque` exists.

Comment: After your edit, your code becomes a duplicate of my solution 2, except it's still `O(n^2)` because of `elem in A[i+1:]` check, which is `O(n)`.

Comment: Oh! But thanks for your comment, got to learn about `deque` which I was unaware about